# Why touchesBegan listener not called(Swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift

I created simple button - `class Btn: UIControl` and then add to parent View. Inside my `Btn` class I have `override func touchesBegan`. 
Why `touchesBegan` not callend when I tapped to the button?
As I think, my `Btn` extends `UIControl` and `Btn` have to call `touchesBegan`.

**My code:**

import UIKit

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        add my button
        let button = Btn()
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

class Btn: UIControl {
    fileprivate let button: UIButton = {
        let swapButton = UIButton()
        let size = CGFloat(50)
        swapButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        swapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return swapButton
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        //        Why it not called?
        print("test")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play around with the following code for playgrounds based on your code, and you will understand what's going on. While your control wants to process the `touchesBegan` callback, it has an `UIButton` inside of it, which consumes the event itself. In the example below, the inner button is taking one quarter of the `Btn` size (red part), if you click on it, the "test" text won't get printed. The rest of the `Btn` space (green part) does not contain any other view that would consume the `touchesBegan`, thus clicking there will print "test" text.

I recommend you to take a look at the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/understanding_event_handling_responders_and_the_responder_chain).

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //        add my button
        let button = Btn(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}

class Btn: UIControl {
    fileprivate let button: UIButton = {
        let swapButton = UIButton()
        let size = CGFloat(50)
        swapButton.frame.size = CGSize(width: size, height: size)
        swapButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

        return swapButton
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addSubview(button)
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        addSubview(button)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

        //        Why it not called?
        print("test")
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```